# How to access method within object

Tags: javascript

This is a noob question.  I am familiar with other languages but JS just makes zero sense to me and I cant seem to figure out how to access private methods,  if thats even what it is that I'm trying to access.  JS syntax is just stupid compared to other languages imo.

I have code that looks like this:

```
    loadForm({
        optionA: "somevalue",
        optionB : "Some value",
    }, function(form){
        form.start() //There is a form.stop() method I may use later also as well as .isRunning() and some other things.
        if (form.isRunning()) //This works just fine
        {
             alert("running");  //This works just fine
        }
    }); 
alert(loadForm.form.isRunning());  //This will say form is not defined.
```

The isRunning method works from within the local scope of loadForm,  but when I try to access it from outside loadForm (I have no idea what loadForm is, I assume it's some sort of object and form is defined as a method of that).  Anyway,  point is,  I want to be able to access ALL of the methods that form contains such as isRunning() and some others from another location.  How do I go about accessing form's other methods.

I dont know why it is coded this way as none of it even makes sense,  but its what I have to work with and it cannot change.  Is what I want to do even possible.  I do not want to have to keep initializing "loadForm" every time I need to access this as that wouldnt make any sense at all.

Comment: Based on the current usage, `loadForm` is an function. Not an object. I am guessing you are following a tutorial? You seem to have a very large misunderstanding. Which tutorial are you following?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can declare a variable before calling `loadForm` and pass a reference to `form` to it in a function callback where you were running `form.start()` etc.

```
// >>>> Just to mock loadForm
const loadForm = (obj, cb) => {
    const fn = {
        isRunning: () => 'yes'
    };
    return cb(fn);
}
// <<<<

// One of the calls
let formObj;

loadForm({}, form => {
    form.isRunning();
    formObj = form;
});

// Test here
alert(formObj.isRunning());
```

With < ES 2005 syntax it would be

```
// >>>> Just to mock loadForm
function loadForm(obj, cb) {
    var fn = {
        isRunning: function() { return 'yes' }
    };
    return cb(fn);
}
// <<<<

// One of the calls
var formObj;

loadForm({}, function(form) {
    form.isRunning();
    formObj = form;
});

// Test here
alert(formObj.isRunning());
```